# What to use to store dropdown values which is fetched from api?

Tags: angular

I am very new to Angular and learning a lot here. I have a very small application, mostly doing crud operations. In this I have a around 10 to 15 dropdowns for which the values will come from DB through api.
I have read about Subject, BehaviourSubject, NgRx store etc. I am really confused to know which one to use to store the dropdown values and use them across the application.
I want to consider one scenario, when multiple users use this and if someone updates any of this dropdown values in the backend, it should reflect for the other users.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Group</mat-label>
            <mat-select
              disableRipple
              formControlName="group"
              (opened)="getGroups()"
              [formControlName]="'group'"
              required
            >
              <mat-option></mat-option>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let g of groups" [value]="g.id">{{
                g.groupName
              }}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>

constructor(
    private refService: ReferenceService
  ) {}
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refService.GroupList$.subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log('subscribed', res);
    });
  }
```

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { GroupService } from './group.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ReferenceService {
  public GroupList$: any;

  constructor(private groupService: GroupService) {
    this.getGroups();
  }

  getGroups() {
    this.groupService.getAll().subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        console.log('call made to api', res);
        this.GroupList$ = res;
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log('Error getting List', err);
      },
    });
  }
}
```

By this i am getting the groups from service.. now my question is, if i want to reuse this Groups dropdown in other forms, should i have this code GetGroups in that form or can i have a global object created so that when the application is loaded, all these dropdown values are loaded into a dictionary or observables..

Comment: Please drop the html code for your dropdowns as we don't know if you're using plain html or some UI framework.
I don't know NgRx but if you look at the documentation of Subject and BehaviourSubject you can decide which one better fits your usecase. Both are suitable.

Comment: I am using material UI framework and generating the dropdowns dynamically with the use of JSON data

Comment: Try [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)
```html
<mat-option *ngFor="let food of foodsSubject | async" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
```

Comment: may be i was not clear, i know the data binding but i want to know how to store these values globally and refer them in multiple places. Edited the question

Comment: The best way for that I believe is creating a service (`ng g service properlyNamed`) in which you put the subject as a local variable. Import that service in whichever component you need to use the subject. An (uglier) alternative is to place the subject in you AppComponent and pass it down in html inputs to whichever component needs it but that's very trippy, especially when using a router.

Comment: I added a service and injected that in my component, however, when i log it i am getting undefined.. may be i am doing something wrong. Updated the code in the question

Comment: Subject doesn't have an initial value, therefore getting undefined. If you want or need an initial value use BehaviorSubject instead. After that, the value should update every time you call .next on it, see [subject documentation](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject)

Comment: I created an observable object in the service and now able to get the value in the component, but say I want to use this drop down in 4 forms then every time I initiate the object in the construct the api call triggers right. In my case 4 times. Is this the best practice? Can’t I get once and store it somewhere internally?

Comment: I'm sure you can change your code in a way that you don't need to do that anymore. Nothing should trigger though when you subscribe to an observable, you do that somewhere else. Also, services are singleton, so there's only one instance of it. It doesn't create new instances and therefore do calls again unless you explicitly make it do that.

Comment: absolutely.. i tested this initializing it multiple calls and its all good. Thank you much